# How to read log from log file as it happens

Tags: c#

As per solution posted in following post I have created form to read log files

[BackgroundWorker & Timer, reading only new lines of a log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318583/backgroundworker-timer-reading-only-new-lines-of-a-log-file)

However I am getting `file in use` exception when writing log entries.

help

Comment: _"help"_ - is that your question? Can you perhaps show that you understand the problem, that you know _something_ about how opening, locking, reading and writing files works, that you have pinpointed the problem to a reproducible testcase, or do you just want the damn code fixed?

Comment: Do you mean "when reading" log entries?

Comment: @Nitin you need to properly dispose the streamReader or fileStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do such file access/manipulation I usually take care of two things.

First, for reading I use the following code (see [FileShare enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx)):

```
using (Stream s = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) { ... }
```

Second, I usually write a while loop for opening the file for reading/writing like this (draft code):

```
int tries=0;
while (tries < 10) {
    try {
        // try to open file for your operation
        break;
    } catch (IOException) {
        tries++;
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Accidently I used FileShare.Read first time in my answer instead of the more appropriate FileShare.ReadWrite. Now I've corrected it.

Comment: It is actually possible for a file to be concurrently written to and read. As demonstrated by [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) for viewing logs as they are being written, which seems to be what the OP is trying to replicate.

Comment: I just tried to give some general ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your log reading code opens the file in [ReadWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) mode. See the excellent answer to this other post for a full explanation: [How do I open an already opened file with a .net StreamReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897796/how-do-i-open-an-already-opened-file-with-a-net-streamreader)